# Python poppler Qt5 Document load error

Tags: python, qt5, poppler

Though the documentation at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-poppler-qt5/) clearly states

```
d = popplerqt5.Poppler.Document.load('file.pdf')
```

doing so results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Document.load(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I'm using Debian Testing.

```
python3             : 3.4.3-7
python3-pyqt5       : 5.5.1+dfsg-3
libpoppler-qt5-1    : 0.26.5-4
python3-poppler-qt5 : 0.24.2-1+b1
```

Minimum working Example:

```
>>> from popplerqt5 import Poppler as PDF
>>> doc = PDF.Document.load( "trial.pdf" )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Document.load(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is the issue with package in debian. I tried compiling from [source](https://github.com/wbsoft/python-poppler-qt5). This worked fawlessly. I will be filing a bugreport with debian.

**Update:**
This problem has been fixed in version `0.24.2-1+b2`